# AJAX ComboBox - dropdown button missing

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax, combobox

Using an AJAX combobox inside of an accordion control. In fact, its an accordion control nested inside another accordion, if that could be a problem.

Anyway -- I have two combo boxes - on the first one it seems like on any page postback the drop down button to see the list of available items disappears. On the second one, its never there.

Here is the code:

```
  <asp:AccordionPane ID="Pane1" runat="server" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" ContentCssClass="accordionContent" >

<Header>
QUERY VIEW
</Header>

<Content>


        <asp:Label ID="lbl_chkOne" CssClass="label" runat="server" Text="By User" ></asp:Label>
            <input id="chk_One" type="checkbox" onclick="changePane(0,this)" groupKey="query" />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_chkTwo" CssClass="label" runat="server" Text="All Users" ></asp:Label>
            <input id="chk_Two" type="checkbox" onclick="changePane(1,this)" groupKey="query" />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_chkThree" CssClass="label" runat="server" Text="Other" ></asp:Label>
            <input id="chk_Three" type="checkbox" onclick="changePane(2,this)" groupKey="query" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Accordion ID="InnerAccordion" runat="server">
            <Panes>
            <asp:AccordionPane ID="Pane3" runat="server" Visible="true" >
            <Content>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Select a User:" 
                    Style="margin-left:28px" ></asp:Label>

                    <asp:ComboBox ID="cbox_User" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend">
                    </asp:ComboBox>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Select a Month:" 
                                Style="margin-left:28px" ></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter a Price:" 
                                Style="margin-left:28px" ></asp:Label>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Price" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
                            TargetControlID="txt_Date" 
                            Format="MMMM yyyy" 
                            OnClientShown="onCalendarShown"
                            OnClientHidden="onCalendarHidden"
                            BehaviorID="calendar1" >
                </asp:CalendarExtender>
                <br />
                </asp:Panel>
            </Content>
            </asp:AccordionPane>
            <asp:AccordionPane ID="Pane4" runat="server" Visible="true" >
            <Content>
              <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Select a Group:" 
                    Style="margin-left:28px" ></asp:Label>

                    <asp:ComboBox ID="cbox_Group" runat="server" >
                    <asp:ListItem Text="All Groups"> </asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Customers" > </asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Employees" > </asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:ComboBox>

                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Select a Month:" 
                                Style="margin-left:28px" ></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Enter a Price:" 
                                Style="margin-left:28px" ></asp:Label>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                <br />
        </asp:Panel>
            </Content>
```

cbox_User is the one that initially displays the button and then it disappears on postback. cbox_Groups is the one that never shows the button.

Here is the code behind that binds data to cbox_User:

```
        protected void BindUsers()
    {
        IQueryable<AqUser> query = from users in db.AqUser
                                   orderby users.username
                                   select users; 

        cbox_User.DataSource = query;
        cbox_User.DataTextField = "username";
        cbox_User.DataValueField = "username"; 
        cbox_User.DataBind(); 
    }

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db = new DBEntities();
        BindUsers();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            OuterAccordion.Panes[1].Visible = false;
        else
            OuterAccordion.Panes[1].Visible = true; 
    }
```

I couldn't find much on the internet about this except for some posts about it possibily being related to divs / css alignment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not a solution, but I gave up on AjaxControlToolkit some time ago because of unpredictability of this kind, e.g. DropDownListExtenders that wouldn't reliably populate, because of event order problems that became increasingly difficult to troubleshoot as forms got more complicated. I would eliminate anything that's easily replaceable with jQuery, like the Accordion panes. Once I got up to speed on jQuery I never looked back and really everything is easier. The learning curve isn't bad at all, especially when you've spend hours beating your head against a wall over this sort of thing.

Comment: I have run into many of the same issues. I prefer a jQuery AutoComplete extender, but for where I want a ddl to be pre-poulated upon binding the AJAX Combobox out of the box is better than ASP.NET server control. However, the CSS for the AJAX control and all of its idocyncrises make using it on any form that is sligtly come complex than just some basic fields makes using it a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Never could solve this. Must be a big they need to fix.

I used DropDownList instead of ComboBox and it works fine.